# Accessing Email over the REST API

Tags: rest-api

The SOAP API seems to expose the EmailMessage sobject which would allow for downloading details of emails sent through Salesforce.

I do not seem to be able to access this based on the sobject data returned by the 
REST API.

Any idea if this is likely to be included in the REST API?

What are my options?

Would SOAP be the only way to access it?

Comment: Could you create a custom REST endpoint in Apex and deliver it that way?

Comment: This is for a plugin for an open-source email client designed to be used by any user with API access (not just a specific organisation) so would that be an option?

Comment: Any user with API access should be able to access an Apex REST endpoint.  Only if the org didn't support Apex, basically, would I think there would be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EmailMessage` is in fact not accessible over the SOAP API either.

Emails via Salesforce are stored in the `Task` object so you can select from that where `Subject` begins with `"Email: "`. Other Email information is stored within the `Description`.

Comment: Emails are stored in the Task object. To save an email you simply use the `type = Email`. The `whoId` is the `contactId`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does seem that there is a difference here, that does surprise me as well to be honest. I did a test using the Salesforce Workbench and it was not listed in the global describe, editing the URL directly confirmed things.

[image]

The standard [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) for this object do indicate that the usual array of CRUD operations are supported and I cannot find any stated exclusion for the REST API. So yes I would say the traditional SOAP Partner/Enterprise API's are your next best route.

> create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), undelete(), update()

Comment: I can confirm that EmailMessage is not available via the REST API in the current release. We are looking at supporting it in a future release.

Comment: Any idea on a timeline? Should it be available over the SOAP API as per http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm ?