# How to log an email against a contact using the REST API

Tags: rest-api

Using the salesforce REST API, how can i log an email against a contact in salesforce?

Comment: i can query and create `Contacts` using the API. i built-over [this](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php) recipe.

i am now looking at 'getting' an email object and logging a contact against it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Accessing Email over the REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7874/accessing-email-over-the-rest-api) you can't currently access the EmailMessage object via the REST API. Confirmed again in v28.0 of the API:

[image: Salesforce REST API v28.0 does not have access to EmailMessage]

It sounds like your options are to either use the Partner/Enterprise API's or see if you can get by with searching for Tasks where the Subject starts with "Email: ".

Comment: i came across [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8936/3428). The `Email` object is within 0the `Task` object. But i still cannot figure out how to go about accessing it or even logging it against a `Contact/Lead/Account`.